# Case insensitive search using key value in rails and postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have written search functionality which is working, but I want it to be case-insensitive.
How can I make it insensitive, though I don't want to change condition because this is running nicely. All four parameters are optional, if any of them are present based on this condition it works.

```
conditions = {}
conditions['first_name'] = params[:first_name] unless params[:first_name].blank?
conditions['last_name'] = params[:last_name] unless params[:last_name].blank?
conditions['specialities.name'] = params[:speciality] unless params[:speciality].blank?
conditions['locations.zipcode'] = params[:zipcode] unless params[:zipcode].blank?

search = Model.using_scope.where(conditions)
```

I am using PostgreSQL as database which is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using a combination of `LOWER` (sql) and `downcase` (ruby)

```
  search = Model.using_scope
  search = search.where('LOWER(first_name) = ?', params[:first_name].downcase) unless params[:first_name].blank?
  search = search.where('LOWER(last_name) = ?', params[:last_name].downcase) unless params[:last_name].blank?
  search = search.where('specialities.name = ?', params[:speciality]) unless params[:speciality].blank?
  search = search.where('locations.zipcode = ?', params[:zipcode]) unless params[:zipcode].blank?
```